# WM ASF Reader::Raw Video 2 codec

Tags: windows-7, video, multimedia, media-player-classic

i am trying to play a wmv file on the latest version of Media Player classic, and i am getting the following error:

```
Media Player Classic - Home Cinema could not render some of the pins in the graph, you may not have the needed codecs or filters installed on the system:

WM ASF Reader::Raw Video 2
```

please advise how to fix this issue.

Answer (score -1):

you need [Install GoToMeeting Codec](https://www3.gotomeeting.com/codec?P...otomeeting.com)

Comment: You might want to expand your answer somewhat - I'd be interested to know why/how you figured out its this specific codec